# How to get and set data to Firebase with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning the Firebase and Node.js. I want to get my Tweets from Twitter and send them to Firebase. I can retrieve my tweets from Twitter, but couldn't send these tweets to Firebase.

How can I send these tweets retrieved from Twitter to Firebase?

I've tried the following code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

// Initialize
var app = firebase.initializeApp({
    ServiceAccount: {
       projectId: "******",
       clientEmail: "****@gmail.com",
       privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nkey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    },
   databaseURL: "****.firebaseio.com"
}); 

// Set Sample Data
firebase.database().ref('/').set({
    username: "test",
    email: "test@mail.com"
});
```

And I got the following error on console:

```
 Debugger listening on port 5858
 crypto.js:279
  var ret = this._handle.sign(toBuf(key), null, passphrase);
                         ^

Error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
    at Error (native)
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:279:26)
    at Object.sign (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\node_modules\jwa\index.js:54:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:23:24)
    at Object.JWT.sign (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\index.js:137:16)
    at authJwt (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:83:16)
    at fetchAccessToken (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:96:17)
    at app_.INTERNAL.getToken (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:196:14)
    at Zb.getToken (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:28:3496)
    at yh (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myProject\myProject\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:195:334)
 Press any key to continue...
```

Also, this my Firebase rules, I'm using these rules just for test purpose:

```
{
   "rules":
   {  
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
   }
}
```

Comment: it seems, that there is issue with your private key. Can't you pass the path of `privateKey.pem` as an arguement ?

Comment: checkout their quickstart https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/database

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved my problem. I just downloaded **serviceAccount.json** file from Firebase Console and inserted it into my project. The 'Service Account' file contains everything that I need.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'https://*****.firebaseio.com',
    credential: 'myapp-13ad200fc320.json', // This is the serviceAccount.json file
});
```

Then the code below worked nicely.

```
firebase.database().ref('/').set({
    username: "test",
    email: "test@mail.com"
});
```

Comment: "serviceAccount" property is deprecated, you should instead use the "credential" property.

Comment: Where did you store the serviceAccount json file that you added to your project?  Their documentation made it seem like it should be stored locally on your computer but that seems odd since I will be deploying my node server to a hosting provider

Answer (score 16):

This specific syntax/library for service accounts in `node` apps is being deprecated. The new method of reaching firebase on a server (that is, not a consumer app, like IoT or desktop) is the [`firebase admin sdk`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Your initialization code should now go:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

You can still manually key in your credentials, but they're now assigned to a diff't property:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: Verified. From https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup: Earlier versions of the Node.js SDK accepted a serviceAccount property instead of the credential property. Similarly, earlier versions of the Java SDK included a setServiceAccount() method instead of the setCredential() method. While these are both still permitted, they result in a deprecation warning and will be removed in the next major version of the SDKs.

Answer (score 10):

We faced the same problem with AWS Beanstalk. The root cause was because `\n` was replaced by `\\n` in the private key variable.

After adding the replace regexp it was fixed:

```
"private_key": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

Printing the variables into the log could also help isolating the issue.